# How to direct traffic in MVC application: CodeIgniter $routes or __remap() for controller selection?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, routes, hmvc

#### Background:

I am using HMVC plugin for CodeIgniter, but this question is likely for MVC in general.

### The Question:

Should I use `$routes` to match my URL layout in order to have specific controllers/modules called, or should I create `__remap()` functions in each of my controllers to call the next "module" in the url series?

I can implement either of these methods successfully, but I don't really see a clear-cut winner.  I'm looking for a reason to use one method over another (unless a combination of both is more appropriate).

Also, I'm not looking for any help on syntax, so if there are small errors below, you're free to ignore them, I'm simply looking for how to apply MVC (HMVC) best practices to my site.

#### Possible URLs visitors encounter:

Assuming the following URLs are possibly encountered in my application:

```
Main Site:
http://www.example.com

Individual Static Pages:
                   .../staticPage1
                   .../staticPage2

Profession Sections:
                   .../profession1
                   .../profession2

Users Section (Unique to each profession):
                   .../profession#/users
                               .../users/id
                               .../users/dashboard
                               .../users/edit
                               .../users/preferences

Events Section (Unique to each profession):
                   .../profession#/events
                               .../events/id
                               .../events/dates
                               .../events/location
                               .../events/create

Search Page (Unique to each profession):
                   .../profession#/search
```

#### Controllers corresponding to aforementioned URL segments:

and the corresponding controllers:

- Site
- Pages
- Professions (extended as specific profession #'s)
- Users
- Events
- Search

#### CodeIgniter Directory Layout for my Controllers:

which are each acting as their own modules and stored as such:

```
/applications
             /modules
                     /site/
                     /pages/
                     /professions/
                     /users/
                     /events/
                     /search/
```

Each module has a `models`, `views`, and `controllers` sub-directory.

#### Example $routes:

If I were to use the router to achieve all of this, I would use the following `routes` that I have defined in my `config` file:

```
//Defaults
$route['default_controller'] = 'site';
$route['404_override'] = '';

//Users
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/users'] = 'users';
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/users/(:num)(/(:any))?'] = 'users/dashboard/$2';
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/users/(:any)'] = 'users/$2';

//Specific Sections
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/search'] = 'search/eventSearch';

//Events
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/events'] = 'events';
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/events/(:num)(/(:any))?'] = 'events/getById/$2';
$route['(?i)([a-z0-9_-]+)/events/(:any)'] = 'events/getByCategory/$2';

//Profession1
$route['(?i)profession1'] = 'profession1';
$route['(?i)profession1(/(:any)?)'] = 'profession1/$2';


//Profession2
$route['(?i)profession2'] = 'profession2';
$route['(?i)profession2(/(:any)?)'] = 'profession2/$2';

//Pages
$route['(?i)(:any)'] = "pages/index/$1";
```

#### Example __remap() for Professions

I have developed `__remap()` functions that I can use in each controller, if it turns out that that is the best approach.  Here is a sample of one such function for the `Professions` controller:

```
public function _remap( $method )
{
        if( isset( $this->uri->segment(3) ) )
        {
            $method2 = $this->uri->segment(3);
        } else {
            $method2 = 'index';
        }
    if ($method == 'users')
    {
        $method2 = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->module('users');
        $this->users->$method2();
    }
    elseif ($method == 'events')
    {
        $method2 = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->module('events');
        $this->events->$method2();
    }
    elseif ($method == 'search')
    {
        $this->load->module('search');
        $this->search->$method2();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->$method();
    }
}
```

#### Conclusion:

If there's any additional information needed to help solve this problem, just let me know and I'll provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$route` and `remap` can solve similiar problems, but they tend to differ at some extent. As in most cases in CodeIgniter, it's up to you to find the most suitable solution among given ones.

The routes solution gives you a design with good perspective of your intends. You and others are able to see what where every url goes, and personally I prefer this most of the times as it makes it quite manageable.

_remap() comes in handy when there are a lot of similiar (or simple) calls with many different class names (often 2nd uri). Which there might seem to be in your case.
You could strip your _remap function some above and it'd be the best solution in this case.

```
public function _remap( $method )
{
    $function = array(  'users'     =>  'users',
                        'events'    =>  'courses',
                        'search'    =>  'search');
    switch ($method) {
        case 'users':
        case 'events':
        case 'search':
            $method2 = ($this->uri->segment(3) ?: 'index');
            $this->load->module($method);
            $this->$function[$method]->$method2();

            break;
        default:
            $this->$method();

            break;
    }
}
```

So basicly, since you seem to have a simple structure for different calls I say use _remap() over $route in this case. But I suggest you to leave a line of comment in the $route file that describes this behavior for simplier troubleshooting.

Comment: After looking at your answer and doing some more research, I am left wondering if I should even bother worrying about `__remap`ping vs. `$routes` or should I simply store the sub-controllers (`users`, `events`, `search`, etc.) in their respective subfolders of the main parent controller (`profession#`).  Your thoughts?  (Again, I am simply trying to figure out a 'best practices' approach - basically what "everyone" else does. Thanks!

Comment: When perfomance isn't a difference, I'd say to use the method you (and possibly your team) find most logical. Personally, I find the multiple controller solution most logical with this amount of variation.

Comment: When you say multiple controller method, you're speaking of using `route`s, correct?  If so, I agree, that's how I'm leaning now.  Thanks!